# PUT data through fos_rest.request_body ParamConverter - Symfony 3

Tags: php, fosuserbundle, fosrestbundle, symfony

I am working on a REST API with FOS Rest Bundle and FOS User Bundle

The data being **PUT** to the server is:

> {"id":1,"email":"email@example.com","username":"adminuser","enabled":true,"locked":false,"groups"
>   :[]}

The routing looks okay:

> admin_user_put_user                 PUT        ANY      ANY    /admin/users/{id}

It is reaching this code below:

```
/**
 * @ParamConverter("userData", converter="fos_rest.request_body")
 * @View(statusCode=204)
 */
public function putUserAction( $id, User $userData )
{
    $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted( 'ROLE_ADMIN', null, 'Unable to access this page!' );

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $user = $em->getRepository( 'AppBundle:User' )->find( $id );
    $user->setEmail( $userData->getEmail() );
    $user->setEmailCanonical( $userData->getEmailCanonical() );
    $user->setEnabled( $userData->isEnabled() );
    $user->setLocked( $userData->isLocked() );
    $em->flush();

}
```

The problem is that it is not populating **$userData** with the data sent.

Could it be a configuration issue?

```
fos_rest:
    disable_csrf_role: ROLE_API
    view:
        view_response_listener: true
        force_redirects:
            html: true
        formats:
            json: true
        templating_formats:
            json: false
            html: true
        mime_types:
            json: ['application/json', 'application/x-json']
        failed_validation: HTTP_BAD_REQUEST
    body_listener: 
        default_format: json
    param_fetcher_listener: 
        force: true
    allowed_methods_listener: true
    access_denied_listener:
        json: true
    body_converter:
        enabled: true
        # validate: true
        # validation_errors_argument: validationErrors # This is the default value
    exception:
        enabled: true
    routing_loader:
        default_format: json
        include_format: false
    format_listener:
        rules:
            -
                # http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/format_listener.html
                path: ^/admin/users
                priorities: ['json', 'html', 'xml','form']
                fallback_format: ~
                prefer_extension: true
                methods: [ 'get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']
            - { path: '^/', stop: true }
```

I understand the code is a little awkward and welcome suggestions for improvement.

*The absence of the group data in the save code is deliberate, I'll get to that later.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the existence of SensioFrameworkExtraBundle and if it's configured as shown [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/request_body_converter_listener.html) (*sensio_framework_extra* and *fos_rest*).

Also you may try to define a class attribute, so it would map without a body converter (to see if it works):

```
@ParamConverter("userData", class="AppBundle:User")
```

Comment: Thank you, but when I use the **class** converter, it is delivering the values from the database, rather than the request body.  I added the configuration in the original question (apologies for not including it the first time).

Comment: @user2182349 I have tested your code in my sandbox and it works. Try to send only `{"id": 1}` and see if userData id is set with this value. It may be caused by undefined deserialization types.

Comment: @e1dar15 - your mention of the deserialization helped me solve the problem.  The deserializer in the User class was expecting all the attributes, but the client was not sending them all.  I changed the code to use json_decode to deserialize the attributes I needed and set them in the updated object.  Works great.  Thank you for your help!